# bluetooth file sending via BluetoothShare class is not working

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an application where i have **file uri as well as bt device address with me**. I need to send the file to the defined bt device. But, the device picker screen should not be shown. **It should directly start the device sending**.

Obviously, **intent:ACTION_SEND is not an option** here, as it will show the chooser dialog. The main intension of the application is to bypass the chooser dialog and enable user to send selected file to selected device directly.

So, i was trying the following solution suggested in stack-overflow:

```
/*BluetoothDevice device;
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/file.jpg";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)).toString());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, device.getAddress());
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
Uri contentUri = getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);*/
```

But unfortunately, it is not working. After getContentResolver().insert, there is no action taken. Needless to say, i have tried various permissions and other stuffs, but to no effect.

So, people who have used this code, please provide your suggestions. Any help to meet the requirement will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Android code, so I'm adding the [tag:android] and [tag:java] tags. Please fix it if that's not correct.

Comment: I am also facing this problem any solution? I have also tried this code it is working on HTC AMAZE But not on samsung Tablet P1000

Answer (score 0):

Does it produce any exception? Please share your Logcat output.

By the way, make use you have the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

If you are doing a device discovery, add this too in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem. I can show some evidence to solve this problem. After trying this code check outbound transfer queue of your device (to open it, Send a file manually to a device and click the notification icon). Then you can see device has tried to send objects and those were failed. Click on one failure message and you can see pop-up with no file path. I think the problem is though here we are setting the file path using URI to the contentValues it will not be checked in the process. We have to do some thing for this.